# Visual studio online build minutes when using own build server

Tags: azure, tfs, azure-devops

Currently I am analysing a setup for a sharepoint development project in Windows Azure.
I would like to use Visual studio online (TFS online).

Since Visual Studio online doesn't support building sharepoint projects (missing ddl's in de GAC), we need to use an own build server (either a VM in windows azure or a server on-premise).

Now, when you build a project with Visual studio online, you are being charged every minute you build. Because you use CPU power. But do you also pay those minute's if you use you're own custom buildserver?

I cannot find the awnser on any of the sites of windows, so does anyone have expirience with this?

Thanks in advance!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your own build server does not make use of the Hosted Build Cluster of VSO and thus does not count towards your build credits. I can't find any clear indication on the VSO site that an on-premise server is free, only that you're charged for the "Shared Resources" used by your VSO project.

> Shared Resources (per Visual Studio Online account)
>    -
>    A Visual Studio Online account includes resources that are shared across all users and projects on that account.
>
> Build - Build definitions can be created using Visual Studio and can be run on Visual Studio Online. Builds can be configured to run on demand, at a specified interval, or for continuous integration (CI). Build is charged per minute for the actual amount of computing time it takes to build the project.

<sup>http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/pricing/details/visual-studio-online/</sup>

Your on premise build "does not run on VSO". And this is the closest wording to a confirmation or denial. But I can tell from experience that the on premise server indeed does not count towards your "Hosted Build" minutes.

Comment: Thanks! This clears up a lot for me. If not to much work, could you provide me the link to where you have found this information? Thanks!!

Comment: Added source to the post