# Private agent deployment on Azure

Tags: azure, tfs

Currently I'm using a private agent to build the artifacts for an application. Deployment fails with this error

```
Your account has no Build or Release minutes remaining. Retry your Job after 09/01/2017 or visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=320621&clcid=0x409 for more information.
Work items
```

How can I deploy it with my private agent or what is the way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Deployment also using the agent.

According to the error message "`Your account has no Build or Release minutes remaining`", seems you are using the hosted agent to deploy. So, please check the build/release definition, if you select the Private agent for the deployment.

According to [this article](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/setup-admin/team-services/buy-more-build-vs)(1 free Private Pipeline area): `Private agents are now free and unlimited` So, it will not charge the build/release minutes.  But you need to pay for the Agent compute hours in Azure in case you are not the subscriber.

If that sill not work, you can try to setup the build agent on your own machine as bmoore mentioned above.

You can reference below articles, they should be helpful for you:

- [How to Create a Monster Build Agent in Azure for Cheap!](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/peterhauge/2016/08/14/how-to-create-a-monster-build-agent-in-azure-for-cheap/)
- [Visual Studio Team Services Private Build Agents](http://www.francoisdelport.com/2016/03/visual-studio-team-services-private-build-agents/)
- [Visual studio online build minutes when using own build server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22149208/visual-studio-online-build-minutes-when-using-own-build-server)

Comment: In the end I figured out you must also configure the use of the private agent for the release. I'm not quite sure how I did it but it was in the settings around there.

Answer (score 1):

You need to setup a custom build agent and then when you queue the build, select that agent to run the build (or default to your custom build agent).  See: https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/build/actions/agents/v2-windows

Comment: this isn't about the build. it's about the deployment, my agent already built the artifacts.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful if you expanded the question a bit to clarify...

Comment: Turns out I had to set the private agent as an option to deploy it. But I still think the way it's designed it's very hard to find where to choose the agent to deploy the build... even now it's hard for me to remember where it had to be set